# Where in Yii2 init some subdomain settings?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, yii2

I have site with subdomains (news.site.com, events.site.com etc).
I am added to config my custom url rule, who find by requested url article in DB and call article controller with action show

for example: `'news.site.com/some-article-with-custom-url'`
I want find in db article with `url = 'some-article-with-custom-url'` and call actionShow() in ArticleController.

But on news.site.com and events.site.com i want find articles with different site_id (column in db)

news.site.com - `select * from article where site_id = 1 ...`

events.site.com - `select * from article where site_id = 2 ...`

**where I can init some subdomains settings, if on UrlManager level I must already have this settings?**

```
'urlManager' => [
  'rules' = [
    ...
    [
      'class' => 'common\components\ArticleUrlRule'
    ],
  ]
]
```

Implementation of parse req of this class:

```
public function parseRequest($manager, $request) {
   $articleId = Article::getArticleIdByUrl($request->pathInfo);

   if ( !empty($articleId) ) {
        return [
            'article/show',
            [
                'id' => $articleId
            ]
        ];
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this, probably there are other ways, starts from defining each sub-domain as a site on your web server. As you regarded, you may have three sites, one main and two sub-domains, make two additional copies of the `web` folder naming them `news and events` respectively, so in your Yii2 project root directory you will have `web, events and news` directories which they are going to be three documents root for three websites on your web server.

In the `index.php` of each web directory define a variable or a constant to express the `site id` to use it in your application when it is going to be needed:

```
<?php

defined('SITE_ID') or define('SITE_ID', x); // where x is an integer  
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of way of doing this, ranging from easy and hacky to hard and well formed.

I think the best way to do this is to have one URL config:

```
'urlManager' => [
  'rules' = [
    [
      '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    ]
  ]
]
```

Then in your `ArticleController`:

```
public function actionShow($id)
{
  // This might be better as a definition list stored in config or something
  $site = null;
  $sub = Yii::$app->request->hostInfo; // Put some logic here to split out subdomain
  switch($sub){
    case 'site1':
      $site = 1;
  }
  $articleId = Article::find()->where(['id' => $id, 'site' => $site]);
}
```

Sort of thing. It can be made more robust and, in general, better from there but I believe that's a good way to do it.

Comment: '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view' unsuitable, because i have articles in db with urls 'some-article-with-custom-url' and i want render this article by url 'http://news.site.com/some-article-with-custom-url', not a 'news.site.com/article/12345'

Comment: Well, for one it is pseudo code, it is not something to copy and paste and second, it is a mere example, to change it would be `'<controller:[\w-]+>/<title:\w+>'=>'<controller>/view',`

Comment: Nah, that `switch` is correct. You set the `$site` var and that is used to constrain the query.

Comment: sorry, but how this rule find controller if url has be `http://news.site.com/some-article-with-custom-url`?

Comment: It won't since I made a mistake, `'<title:[\w-]+>'=>'article/show',` but that will

Comment: 1) long switch construction with settings in model is a very bad idea 2) i want have this settings globaly, not fro one method or one class

Comment: As I said, you can change that, but then with the information you have given this is currently the best way in my mind. All I know is you have one action with multiple subdomains which switch a `site_id` as such that is the answer

Comment: As for setting it globally: I did say you can add the switch map as a config variable to the application configuration, or even in the database as a variable list of blog/article subdomains with loggable users and article composing etc etc, this is an EXTREMELY simple version

Comment: A god example of how this could work in more complex forms is like how `wordpress.com` works with it's subdomains